# Top rated posts Average rating issue

Tags: comments, query-posts, comment-form, comment-meta

I am trying to show top rated posts, cpt with AVG rating value.I created the custom widget for this. Defaults wp posts data and AVG value is showing correct but a CPT like Movie post not showing correct AVG value. I'm using following code to achieve this. Need help

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
$posttype       = $instance['posttype'];
$postsperpage   = $instance['postsperpage'];
$postorder      = $instance['postorder'];
$avgrt_pos      = $instance['avgrt_pos'];
$image          = $instance[ 'showimage' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
$avgrt_img      = $instance[ 'avgrt_star' ];

// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];


global $wpdb, $post;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT({$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_post_ID), GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID separator ', ') comment_ids FROM {$wpdb->prefix}comments JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta ON {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.comment_id = {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID 
     WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_approved = 1 GROUP BY {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_post_ID", ARRAY_A);



    foreach($results as $key => $value) 
    {
          $c_post_id = $value['comment_post_ID'];
          $comment_ids = $value['comment_ids'];
          $res = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT AVG(`meta_value`) as avg_rate FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'rating' AND `meta_value` != '' AND comment_ID IN ($comment_ids) ORDER BY meta_value" );

          $results[$key]['avg_rate'] = $res[0]->avg_rate;
          //var_dump($res);
    }

    # sort value by high rated
    if($postorder=='DESC'){
        $sortOrder = SORT_DESC;
    }else{
        $sortOrder = SORT_ASC;
    }
    # avg stars
    if($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str1'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-1';
    }elseif($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str2'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-2';
    }elseif($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str3'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-3';
    }elseif($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str4'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-4';
    }elseif($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str5'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-5';
    }elseif($avgrt_img=='avgrt_str6'){
        $avgrt_img = 'star-6';
    }else{
        $avgrt_img = 'star-1';
    }



    $avg_rate = array_column($results, 'avg_rate');
    array_multisort($avg_rate, $sortOrder, $results);


    $top_rated = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) 
    {

        if($result['avg_rate'] && $result['comment_ids'] )
        {
            $top_rated[] = $result['comment_post_ID'];
         }

    }


   $args = array(
      'post_type' => $posttype,
      'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage,
      'post__in' => $top_rated,
      'orderby' => 'post__in',
      'post_status' => 'publish', 
   );

  $top_rated_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    //var_dump($top_rated_posts);
  // The Loop
  if ( $top_rated_posts->have_posts() ) 
  {
     echo '<div class="wpcr_top_rated_container"><ul>';
     $i=0;
     while ( $top_rated_posts->have_posts() ) 
     {
        $top_rated_posts->the_post();
        $postid= get_the_ID();

            /* grab the url for the full size featured image */
            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'thumbnail');
            $get_post_link = get_permalink();

            if($image == 'true'){
                if(!empty($featured_img_url)){
                    $feaimage = '<a href="'.esc_url($get_post_link).'"><img src="'.esc_url($featured_img_url).'" alt=""></a>';
                }else {
                    $feaimage = '';
                }
            }   
            $topr_desc = get_the_content();
            $words = 15;
            $more = ' […]';
            $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $topr_desc, $words, $more );

            $avgrating = '<div class="wpcr_aggregate"><a class="wpcr_inline" title=""><span class="wpcr_averageStars_tprt '.$avgrt_img.'" data-wpcravg="'.number_format((float)$results[$i]['avg_rate'], 2, '.', '').'"></span></a><span class="avg-inline">'.number_format((float)$results[$i]['avg_rate'], 2, '.', '').'</span></div>';

                    //var_dump($results[$i]['avg_rate']);   

            if($avgrt_pos == 'before'){
                $avg_bef = $avgrating;
            }
            if($avgrt_pos == 'after'){
                $avg_aft = $avgrating;
            }

                $output = '<li>';
                $output .= '<div class="left">'.$feaimage.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="right"><a href="'.esc_url($get_post_link).'"><span class="wpcr_title" title="">'.get_the_title().'</span></a>';
                $output .= $avg_bef.'<div class="desc">'.$excerpt.'</div>'.$avg_aft.'</div></li>';
                echo $output;
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';

    wp_reset_query();
  } else {
    echo 'Sorry, no post found.';
  }

 echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses this:

```php
number_format((float)$results[$i]['avg_rate'], 2, '.', '')
```

And if we look at where `$i` is set, we see this just before the loop:

```php
     $i=0;
```

and this:

```php
        $i++;
```

But I don't see how this maps in any way to the current post when there's a conditional, meaning that not everything in the results array is included in the post query.

Instead, don't use  `$i`, use the post ID, and store the post ID as the key.

Some further notes:

- This will not scale, as the number of posts increases the query will get slower, and as the number of ratings increase, the query will get slower. 2x as many posts won't mean twice as slow, it'll get slower faster than that. It'll be fast when there's not much data, and it'll grind to a halt afterwards.
- It could be thousands of times faster and more efficient to just recalculate a posts average rating when a new rating is added, and store the average in post meta
- `wp_reset_query` has no place here. Unless you're using `query_posts` don't use it. Perhaps you meant to use `wp_reset_postdata`?
- If you're going to write raw SQL queries, prepare your statements. Don't just put variables inside the query strings, that's dangerous! `$wpdb->prepare` is your friend, sanitise and make those queries safe
- There are a lot of unnecessary variables, for example why use `$output`? Just echo them and save the effort of another variable, it's a waste of resources, adds  overhead when reading and typing out, and it has no benefit
- `$avg_bef` and `$avg_aft` are only assigned if that position is chosen, which will generate PHP warnings ( and in PHP 8 will generate PHP fatals ), assign them a default value beforehand of `$avg_bef = '';` etc, don't just pull them out of thin air

Comment: Post ID doesn't return correct avg value.